# How to set soap header for UTF-8 encoding Suds Jurko Python

Tags: python, soap, client, suds

I am creating my own factory xml elements using `client.factory.create`

I have headers which I set prior to this using Attribute and Element then using client.set_options.

But I have an issue with empty strings as they don't parse and i receive an error:

```
   raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:28:64: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

I have googled and it seems I need to add the content type to the header. Please can someone show me how I can do this using:

request_header.append

Answer (score 0):

The result should look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

can you figure it from there?